# Wordpress remove related posts from my post content

Tags: php, wordpress, zemanta

I am using Zemanta related post in my wordpress blogs for SEO purpose. I installed it successfully. At the single post page (blog page) it is coming two times one on the right sidebar as a widget and another one on the bottom of my post content. Is there any way to remove it from second place means from the bottom of post content not from the right sidebar.

Comment: not without you sharing some code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method of removing the related posts below the post but still have the side widget would be by using CSS and not display the content below.

```
#zem_rp_first {
    display:none;
}
```

During an update if they decide to change the name of the ID you may have to edit this field but without editing the plugin itself, this would be the easiest way.

Comment: Not a problem at all :)